# Dictionary<int, MyObject> is unsupported in Ria services. Do you know how it can be exposed to client application?

Tags: c#, ria

One of my class has a property:

```
Dictionary<int, MyObject>
```

I get the error that it is unsupported.  Is there a way to expose Dictionary via Ria service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a System.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<int, MyObject> which will then be passed over the wire.  For some reason the serializer doesn't support Dictionaries,

Comment: I get Error 5 Operation named 'Blabla' does not conform to the required signature. Parameter types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of entities or complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types.

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend. ;o)

It [looks](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/170186/384995.aspx) like you cannot use complex types here.